# nil is getting saved for an image in carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

A product can have multiple images. But each image should be uploaded one at a time.

Here is the schema for the product

```
create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.json     "images"
  end
```

Here is the carrierwave mounting

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount_uploader  :images, ProductUploader

end
```

Here is the carrierwave generator

```
class ProductUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  # storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  # def default_url
  #   # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  #   # ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  #
  #   "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  # end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  # process scale: [200, 300]
  #
  # def scale(width, height)
  #   # do something
  # end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  # version :thumb do
  #   process resize_to_fit: [50, 50]
  # end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  # def extension_whitelist
  #   %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  # end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  # def filename
  #   "something.jpg" if original_filename
  # end

end
```

Here is the view

```
<%= simple_form_for @product, method: :post, url: save_image_path do |f| %>

        <%= f.file_field :avatar_1 %>

        <%= f.submit :submit %>

    <% end %>
```

Here is the controller

```
class UploadController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @product = Product.find(1)
  end

  def create
    byebug
    @product = Product.find(1)
    @product.images = params[:product][:avatar_1]
    @product.save

  end


end
```

[image]

But the nil is getting updated in the images of product, instead of image. Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: any reason for  json column for images ? why not using another table with string data type ?

Comment: You mean to say, have another model image. Which has one column image:string, and product will have has many images?

Comment: yes, right i usually do that, that works good

Comment: Yeah man, that should be a good idea .. but I thought I need not do all that and scratching my head, anyways will go for has_many. Thanks

Comment: did you permit changes to this filed in the model? (using the strong parameters: params.permit(products: [:images]) im using json field type btw, and it works.

Comment: I need not permit, If I don't mass assign